# Problems with PHP script on IIS 7 server

Tags: php, iis

I new to PHP and I am having problems porting some PHP scripts to a server running IIS 7. PHP seems to be installed correctly, see http://econresource.cid.no/models/models/info.php. But the script http://econresource.cid.no/models/models/model1.php does not execute as expected.

For a working version of the model1.php script, remove .cid from the URL above. I suspect this is some kind of security issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your using short open tags and support for them is disabled, change

```
<?
```

to

```
<?php
```

you can see in your phpinfo -
**short_open_tag OFF**

Comment: Thanks Dagon, updated **short_open_tag** to **ON** and it's working.

Comment: better to update the script, short open tags are genrally a bad idea